# Open jsp file in a popup (and execute a method before opening it) from a jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1, struts1

Since I'm not very familiar with struts 1.2, I'm coming to you for help : in the picture I enclosed, you can see a page whose purpose is to update information about a specific person. Each person can be identified with an unique id (the birthdate is included in it). With this id, I can call a web service. In return, I get personal information of the person : name, first name, birthdate, gender, address, ...

Sometimes the information we have can be outdated (for example, the person moved out and lives elsewhere) and that's why we have the button you see in the middle of the picture ("Synchroniser avec le ..." which is French for "Synchronize with the ... ").

When I click on the button, I'd like a popup to appear with the latest information about the person (So that means before the popup appears, I call the webservice with the id as the parameter.). Then, in this popup I can choose whether to update the information or cancel the operation. Either way, the popup closes and I get back on the page you see in the picture.  How can I do that ?

Do I have to add a new action in struts-config.xml ?

Thanks in advance

P.S : Unfortunately, I'm not sure how much code I can show you (confidentiality stuff)

[image: Worker information update]

Comment: It's not clear which part of the task you're having issues with. If you open a popup from this window then you have access to the parent window and can call JavaScript functions on it, e.g., to update field values. If you open a "popup", e.g., a dialog box in the existing DOM, then you don't even need to play cross-window JS games and can access fields directly.

Comment: @DaveNewton basically the screenshot you see is a form where some information are loaded (like name, first name, birthdate, address, ...). Since those are personal information, I had to remove them in the picture.

Like I said in the original post, the button's purpose is to update those information. And this is where I'm stuck. I'd like the button to do 2 things : 
- call the web service via a Java method (it's already implemented) to get the new value of those variables (well only the address is the most likely to change in a person's life)
- once it's done, a pop-up must appear  [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] with these updated information.
In this popup, besides the personal information that are displayed, there are 2 button : one to update the personal information (then you get back on the page you see in the screenshot with the updated values) and a second one to cancel the operation (you don't update the information)